# script not working when executed from hosted server

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have this script that works fine when it is executed from a Visual Studio Code terminal, but when it is executed from my hosted website server (A2 Hosting), I get the error bellow. This is my script, it is pretty much the example I got from a website.

```
const chromeLauncher = require('chrome-launcher');
const axios = require('axios');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  // Initializing a Chrome instance manually
  const chrome = await chromeLauncher.launch({
    port: 7822,
    chromeFlags: ['--headless']
  });
  const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:${chrome.port}/json/version`);
  const { webSocketDebuggerUrl } = response.data;

  // Connecting the instance using `browserWSEndpoint`
  const browser = await puppeteer.connect({ browserWSEndpoint: webSocketDebuggerUrl });

  //await browser.close();
  await chrome.kill();
})();
```

I have a feeling my problem has to do with 'localhost', it doesn't seem to make sense to use this when executed from the hosted server, but I am not sure what I could put instead.
This is the error I am getting:

> (node:9737) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Parse Error:
> Expected HTTP/
> at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:509:22)
> at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
> at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:307:12)
> at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:282:9)
> at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:221:10)
> at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) (node:9737)

Thanks ahead of time, I have been trying to figure this out for days.

Answer (score 0):

Evidently you can't use puppeteer with their basic hosting plan.  I also have problems with puppeteer on a2hosting, but had different errors:

> FATAL:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(117)] No usable sandbox!

and with sandbox disabled-

> error occurred Failed to launch the browser process!
> [0118/202801.621209:ERROR:bus.cc(393)] Failed to connect to the bus:
> Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file
> or directory [0118/202801.621276:ERROR:platform_thread_posix.cc(135)]
> pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable (11)

I contacted support and they said:

> These errors are related to the limitations that exist in your
> existing hosting plan; you'd need a VPS to properly host a Puppeteer
> application https://www.a2hosting.com/vps-hosting/managed